# TypeError: Every item in the descriptions list must be an AccessDescription

Tags: python, python-3.7, gspread

I've just updated my python version and I started getting this weird error, how can I solve, is it related to python version or something else?? I've already tried searching for this error on the internet but didn't find anything

```py
  File "/home/maaz/QlashBotCogs/qpc/qpc.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.qpc_sheet = self.client.open('Discord Qlash Prime Community Leaderboard').sheet1
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 73, in request
    headers=headers
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/breadcrumbs.py", line 341, in send
    resp = real_send(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 381, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 374, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/home/maaz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 216, in get_subj_alt_name
    ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 159, in inner
    result = func(instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py", line 134, in extensions
    self._backend, self._x509
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py", line 238, in parse
    value = handler(backend, ext_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py", line 379, in _decode_authority_information_access
    return x509.AuthorityInformationAccess(access_descriptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 269, in __init__
    "Every item in the descriptions list must be an "
TypeError: Every item in the descriptions list must be an AccessDescription
```

Comment: Please show your code that is generating the error.